# Browser extensions to custom enhance text information, alternative to "Find in page"

Tags: web-browser, data-visualization, text-search

I frequently find myself combing through a number of web pages looking for particular keywords and related topics.  I want something better than the browser's "find in page" function (which highlights the word I type, so +1 to that tool).

Example:  I'm looking at several "call for papers" to publish my research, and each one has a list of topics like the one below:

> Design, implementation, and analysis of network architectures and
>   algorithms  Enterprise, datacenter, and storage area networks  SDNs
>   and network programming  Experimental results from operational
>   networks or network applications  Economic aspects of the Internet 
>   Energy-aware communication  Insights into network and traffic
>   characteristics  Network management and traffic engineering  Network
>   security and privacy  Network, transport, and application-layer
>   protocols  Networking issues for emerging applications 
>   Fault-tolerance, reliability, and troubleshooting  Operating system
>   and host support for networking  P2P, overlay, and content
>   distribution networks  Resource management, QoS, and signaling 
>   Routing, switching, and addressing  Techniques for network measurement
>   and simulation  Wireless, mobile, and sensor networks

Here I want a browser extension to highlight anything related to, say, software defined networking, or data centre networks.  Furthermore, I want to tell the browser extension what interested me on this page, and it will help me find similar stuff on other pages, as well as aggregate my searches so that I can compare them.

More broadly, I want a browser extension that makes what I'm looking for in a page stand out, say, by enlarging or highlighting keywords and key phrases, or relating content to previous searches using some sort of overlay.  It would also aggregate data that I've expressed interest in for viewing later.  Ideally there would be some intelligence where the software tries to predict what I'm interested in (the same way any modern search engine works).

Does this exist?

Comment: Is any browser okay, or is Chrome *required*?

Comment: I use Chrome, but I'm interested in software for any browser.  I'll not specify in the question...